# math.h was not found at compile time: Hydra (Cygwin)

Tags: cygwin, hydra

I`m using **Hydra** with **Cygwin**. Can anyone help me with this error?
When I using -x option, this error is shown:

```
[ERROR] -x option is not available as math.h was not found at compile time
```

my Cygwin consists recommended packages and even more than that (125MBs)

Comment: Why is this tagged as [tag:security]? The question itself has nothing to do with security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give little information. It seems like Hydra is some package that is pre-compiled for Cygwin? And when you run Hydra with `-x`, it gives you the error message?

If this is the case, then the creator of the Cygwin package for Hydra did not have the `math.h` C header file available when it has been compiled. That is rather odd, perhaps the `-lm` linker flag for GCC was missing. So this is something that you need to take to the package maintainer in Cygwin.

In case that you have compiled it yourself, it is really strange that you have a C compiler which does not ship with `math.h`.

If you have installed it via a package and you need this to run on Windows, you might have to install the dependencies and compile Hydra yourself.

Comment: Thanx for answer, but I use -x option within hydra command and -lm is not useful here as I see.